# Django ~Q queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

Here is my error, and I really can't find anything similar to my problem:

```
from django.db.models import Q    
_entry = Entry.objects.get(Q(slug=slug, author=self.author) & ~Q(id=self.id))
```

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Q'

Comment: Could you show more of the error message? (previous lines)

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: that's odd, this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to what you are trying to do with `Q`s, would be to use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter)+[`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)+[`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
_entry = Entry.objects.filter(slug=slug, author=self.author).exclude(id=self.id).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only the '&' but also Comma ',' represents AND in django Q objects so you can also try:

```
from django.db.models import Q    
_entry = Entry.objects.get(Q(slug=slug), Q(author=self.author) , ~Q(id=self.id))
```

Although I couldn't recreate the error that you get. Also please make sure slug,self.author and self.id have proper type of data to go into respective fields.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) are the docs for complete reference

Comment: The docs you linked to say 'Q objects can be combined using the & and | operators'.

Comment: Plz notice in the examples in the docs, & is never used, instead a comma is used and in direct sql translation you will see it translates to sql AND..

Comment: Im sorry ur right.. & also does work. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: correct @Anentropic . I just want to get a result keeping things just as in asked question. Otherwise alecxe answer should be the best solution